# How can I make the "Editing help" link open a custom page in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I used to have an older version of MediaWiki installed where the "Editing help" link (the one at the bottom of the page when editing a regular page) would take me to a custom page. It would contain the most common formats and styles I use in a page there, so it was really handy to have.

[image]

I've since upgraded to a newer version of MediaWiki and the "Editing help" link takes me to the editing help for all of mediawiki:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Editing_pages

I don't remember if or how I set this to link to a custom page, and searches on the Internet aren't bringing up anything helpful. How can I customize this link to go to my own page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your wiki edit **MediaWiki:Edithelppage** and add the title of your help page, e.g. **Help:Editing**